# Inserir imagens no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom tarde, inseri uma grande quantidade de informações em uma tabela em meu banco de dados por meio de um arquivo .csv usando a linha de comando LOAD DATA INFILE e também tenho uma tabela de relacionamento onde ficará registrado o ID do produto e  o caminho da(s) foto(s) desse produto, mas estou tentando escapar de ter que cadastrar as fotos manualmente, no caso, realizando um upload da(s) foto(s) por um form em minha área administrativa.
Sei que parece mágica mas existe alguma forma de fazer isso, relacionar o produto com imagens de uma pasta e guardar o caminho na tabela ou alguém já passou por uma situação assim?

Comment: Isso parece mágica... :| Onde tem a informação de qual imagem é de qual produto?

Comment: Olá @KaduAmaral foi justamente por isso que postei aqui, para saber se alguém tem alguma dica de como fazer isso, tentei algumas possibilidades mas sem sucesso.

Comment: se você tem o id do produto e o caminho da foto de cada produto é só fazer o robô abaixo.

Comment: Olá @lolol, foi exatamente o que fiz, criei um robô como indicado, ficou muito legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim.

Coloque as fotos no seu computador preservando a estrutura de pastas e faça um robô (pode ser um php) que faça um full table scan (ou seja, um select all e um loop nesse resultado) procurando pela foto de cada produto. Se a foto for encontrada faça um update numa nova coluna (fotoencontrada), renomeie a foto para o id do produto e a mova para uma pasta comum.

Depois é só fazer o upload de todas as fotos através de um ftp.